# Finding date of Esri Satellite Imagery using QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, basemap, quickmapservices

In QGIS, I added the 'Esri Satellite' layer using QuickMapServices and want to determine what date/dates the imagery is from.

I've tried selecting the layer and using 'identify' but nothing comes up.

Comment: What satellite imagery? A WMS service?

Comment: Not a WMS it's an ArcGIS REST service ~ https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/

Comment: According to the metadata `SRC_DATE` is available, but as far as I can tell you can't query the service through QuickMapServices.  You may need to load instead as an ArcGIS REST service, and call it directly